# Insert and update merge using EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using sql azure as storage.

I have a data set (list of entities) which has both new and old records. I have no way to identify which record is for update or insert. I need a way using EF to send the whole  thing to db, using some statement which will identity what to do with it (meaning update or insert)

I have been able to find merge using object context but it doesn't fit my purpose.

If anything is unclear, please ask.

Comment: Is the obvious solution - namely loop through the list, query the database for each entity if it exists in the DB and then either set the state to Modified or to Added - no option for you?

Comment: data is quite huge and yes it is an option but it will take lot of time. thats why i am trying to avoid it.

Comment: I think there is no other way using EF than iterating through the list. The only alternative is probably to write a Stored Procedure that gets the list passed and performs update or insert directly in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, but in all of them EF somehow has to know which entities are new and which are old.

- Let EF do the change tracking. That is, query and save from the same context instance. This is the obvious answer and I'll not say too much more about it since I assume your architecture doesn't allow this or you wouldn't be asking the question.
- Have some characteristic of the entity that lets you know whether or not it is old or new. This is by far the most common thing to do if you can't use EF change tracking. Usually this is done using the primary key value--something like zero/negative number/null for new entities, everything else for old entities.
- Query the database for each entity to see if it exists or not.